# jqm scrolling footer and viewport strange behaviors

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollview, viewport

I'm creating a mock-up of a function to be added to a mobile version of a site. The idea is to have a horizontally scrolling footer of links with vertically scrolling content; in effect, recreating the functionality of the native iOS behavior when double-tapping the home button.

Problem: when the page loads, it appears the viewport is not getting recalculated to match the new content area height. This leaves an ugly blank area (apparently the size of the URL bar in iOS Safari) below the scrollable footer.

I've tried adding a timeout to recalculate the height (using the function in scrollview.js). When using a fixed-position footer, the footer behaves strangely but eventually reappears in the expected place - the blank space remains, however.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/apszs/1/) to jsfiddle code.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUs40.png) to imgur screenshot from my iPhone.

Comment: any errors? BTW nice scrolling navbar/footer +1 just for that

Comment: Enabling Developer flag on iOS Safari produces no errors.